# What happens if you signal (os signal, not pthread_mutex_unlock) on process blocked on pthread_mutex_wait

Tags: linux, unix, pthreads, signals, posix

What baffles me is that `pthread_mutex_lock` does not have `E_INTR` as return value. Although `pthread_cond_wait` can be spurious waken up and return 0, because of the while loop and Mesa monitor semantics, this is not a problem.

So if a process is blocked by `pthread_mutex_lock`, and you send a signal to wake it up, after signal handler is executed, what will happen? Are there any mechanism to avoid this spurious wake up?

Comment: Just wrote testing program. Seems pthread library developer handle this. Unlike `pthread_cond_wait` which exposes `E_INTR`, `pthread_mutex_lock` handled this internally. What's weird is that why `pthread_mutex_lock` is not marked as reentrant safe function?

Answer (score 1):

> if a process is blocked by pthread_mutex_lock, and you send a signal to wake it up, after signal handler is executed, what will happen?

If the signal handler didn't invoke any async-signal unsafe operations, then after the handler returns, the process will continue waiting for the mutex.

If the signal handler did invoke an async-signal unsafe operation (e.g. unlocked the mutex), the behavior is undefined: *anything* can happen, including (but not limited to) crashing, blocking forever, appearing work "normally", etc. etc.